# Can we change the LogMgrFlushInterval value for MSMQ?

Tags: msmq

Microsoft cautions against changing this value in their [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738482(v=ws.10).aspx), but the documentation itself appears to be incorrect -- it states that the default value is 50ms, while our testing shows it is actually 10ms. If we could safely bump the value up to 50ms, we would probably be happy, so the question is -- can we do that and not loose the transactional guarantees that MSMQ provides?

PS. A quick background for "why in the world would we want to mess with this value" -- we have an application that sits on top of couple transactional MSMQ queues. The application polls one of the queues periodically, and if it finds a message, it will begin processing. The application itself works fine. But what we are seeing is that as soon as we do a read from the queue, MSMQ will start writing to disk at a rate of over 50 writes per second, and will continue to do so for about 10 seconds after each single read done by the application (it appears to be transaction log flushing). If we increase LogMgrFlushInterval value to 50ms, the write rate drops to about 12 per second. The reason we care about this is that at 50 writes per second, multiplied by the number of running application instances, the resulting load essentially overwhelms the CPU on our NAS. We are looking at other options (reduce the number of running instances, increase the application polling interval beyond 10 seconds, get a bigger NAS), but those all cost more time/money compared to changing the flush interval.

Answer (score 1):

All parts of the transaction must be written to disk for recovery purposes. The longer the interval, the larger the window of opportunity for data loss should there be a hardware failure. 
The amount of reads sounds excessive. How many messages are you processing per second?

Comment: It's not the reads (which we control) that are a problem, it's the writes that MSMQ does outside of our control. The number of writes caused by buffer flushing does not appear to correlate with the number of messages written to the queue. Most of our server process less than 10 messages per second, and still do 50+ writes/sec.

Back to the topic of increasing flush interval -- are you saying that our chances of losing data are proportionate to the interval size? (i.e. by going from 10ms to 50ms we have 5x chance of losing a message?)